# Dockerized Application in Kubernetes for multi-tenancy

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I currently have a dockerized application that I'd like to have the deployment model of multi-tenancy. The end goal for me is to be able to deploy the multiple application instances without the need to spin up a VM for every instance.

I've looked at Kubernetes, and I'm looking at pods for now, but would like some practical guidance as I'm inexperienced in Kubernetes.

How would I, if possible, practically do this? And how would the deployment look like?

Answer (score 2):

In Kubernetes, you may isolate your tenants by using namespaces. Each tenant will get its own namespace to spin up pods and other namespace scoped objects. Furthermore, you can define [role and rolebinding](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/) and implement RBAC to grant access to a particular namespace.

**[Namespaces](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/namespaces/)**

> In Kubernetes, namespaces provide a mechanism for isolating
> groups of resources within a single cluster. Names of resources need
> to be unique within a namespace, but not across namespaces.
> Namespace-based scoping is applicable only for namespaced objects
> (e.g. Deployments, Services, etc) and not for cluster-wide objects
> (e.g. StorageClass, Nodes, PersistentVolumes, etc).